# Why is my cookie prefixed with __Host- getting rejected by Chrome?

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to leverage the [cookie name prefix convention](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05#section-3.2) to get the browser to help me set secure cookies.  My cookie is named `__Host-cookie` and it is set like this:

```
__Host-cookie=value; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 11 Aug 2023 04:58:13 GMT; Max-Age=86399; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

However Chrome refuses to set it and shows this error in the network log:

> This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because it used the “__Secure-“ or “__Host-“ prefix in its name and broke the additional rules applied to cookies with these prefixes as defined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05

The cookie itself seems fine to me.  Only thing I can think of is that because I'm testing using a service running on my own machine, I'm setting the cookie from `localhost` and that maybe fails this requirement from the IETF docs

> Set from a URI whose "scheme" is considered "secure" by the user agent

I expected localhost to be exempt though since it's exempt from other conventions that require a secure host. For example Chrome will happily sent a cookie flagged `Secure` to a server running on `http://localhost`.

Does anyone see something wrong with my cookie?

Answer (score 2):

> If a cookie's name begins with "__Host-", the cookie MUST be:
>
> 1. Set with a "Secure" attribute
> 2. Set from a URI whose "scheme" is considered "secure" by the user agent.
> 3. Sent only to the host which set the cookie. That is, a cookie named "__Host-cookie1" set from "https://example.com" MUST NOT contain a "Domain" attribute (and will therefore be sent only to "example.com", and not to "subdomain.example.com").
> 4. Sent to every request for a host. That is, a cookie named "__Host-cookie1" MUST contain a "Path" attribute with a value of "/".

In your case it violates rule 2 as `http://localhost` isn't secure

Comment: Was hoping I missed something else since localhost is exempt from some other "must be secure" rules, but that's the only thing I see as well.  Thank you

Comment: @BeetleJuice I'm curious to know when there's exception to that, I've never encountered one.

Comment: Chrome will happily respect a cookie flagged Secure from an insecure localhost server.  There are several more examples of browsers making exceptions for localhost.  See https://web.dev/when-to-use-local-https/#use-httplocalhost-by-default

Comment: Actually that very page I linked above states that secure cookies will not work across browsers on http://localhost: "Chrome and Safari don't set Secure cookies on localhost, but Firefox does. In Chrome, this is considered a bug"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in chrome which is tracked [here](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40196122) (and [here](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40202941)). As for Firefox, I tested it and it is being set on localhost. As a workaround, you can use a tool like [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to create a certificate and use it on your local server. [See here](https://web.dev/articles/how-to-use-local-https#quick-reference) for some guidance.